# - selected="{{ associationId==association.value }}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I migrated to VueJS 2, and now, Chrome is telling me:

> - `selected="{{ associationId==association.value }}"`: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">`, use `<div :id="val">`.
> - `<select v-model="associationSelected">`: inline selected attributes on `<option>` will be ignored when using v-model. Declare initial values in the component's data option instead.
> - invalid expression: `:selected="item.list=={{ federationId==federation.value }}"`

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="association_id" class="text-bold">Asociacion</label>

    <select name="association_id" v-model="associationSelected" id="association_id"
            class="form-control" v-on:change="getClubs(associationSelected)">
    <option v-for="association in associations" v-bind:value="association.value"
            selected="{{ associationId==association.value }}">
        {{ association.text }}
    </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Message is quite explicit, but when I try to use `:select`, I get

> invalid expression: `:selected="item.list=={{ federationId==federation.value }}"`

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `v-bind:selected="associationId == association.value"` should work

Comment: It gives me: Property or method "associationId" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in <Root>)

Comment: on my view, I have at the end,  let associationId = "";

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro you need to add `associationId` to your data object

Comment: but I get this data via php, so how should I declare it? associationId:associationId ???

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro set in your data as `associationId: ''` and then when you receive the data you can do `this.associationId = data`

Comment: but this data is rendered in server, not via ajax, so, in Vue file, I never get the value, I have to pass it from view to vue...

Comment: I don't really know why, but removing v-bind:selected="associationId == association.value" fixed the problem, and now it is working... I don't really know how does it remember the selected option.... anyway! solved

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Cool, nice to hear that!